# Внутренний цикл for в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, почему вложенный цикл для каждого значения переменной i, выполняется ещё девять раз?

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
        document.write(j);
    }
    document.write(i + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: А Вы какого результата ожидали?

Comment: По определению цикла код, содержащийся внутри тела цикла, повторяется столько раз, сколько возможно изменение переменной цикла.

Comment: я просто начал изучаю JS и хочу логический как то понять это!

Comment: Не поленитесь прочесть чего-нибудь о циклах. Вопрос бессмысленный.

Comment: karmadro4 я так и делаю, читаю не по одной книге, про вложенные циклы  ничего еще не попадалось просто.

Comment: @adidassler, не знаю, не знаю... Код исполняется точно так, как вы написали, и это очевидно всем, кроме вас. Возможно, стоит отредактировать вопрос и раскрыть, что конкретно непонятно, что вы ожидали и т.п.

Comment: Возможно автору надо потренироваться на чем-нибудь простом, консольном ... м.б. бэйсик ?

Comment: @avp,в бэйсике будет проще понять все эти вещи чем в javascript??

Comment: Конечно проще, BASIC был разработан для вводного обучения алгоритмическим языкам.

Comment: @avp @karmadro4, а по окончанию цикла переменная i какое значение получает?

Answer (score 6):

Потому что это вложенный цикл.

**Добавлено из комментария.**

Код, который находится внутри цикла, выполняется заданное количество раз, в вашем случае - 9 раз. Соответственно вложенный цикл будет выполнятся тоже 9 раз, а код внутри него - 9*9 итого 81 раз, чисто логически читаем код: натыкаемся на первый цикл, делаем первый проход, во время прохода натыкаемся на еще один цикл, делаем девять проходов по нему, затем выводим i, далее возвращаемся в начало цикла для второго прохода и так 9 раз.

Comment: а по содержательней как то можно обьяснить!?

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.